# nested objects with arbitrary keys to key-value objects with jq

Tags: json, key, jq

There is an json object with n nested objects, where the key ist arbitrary and the nested objects have all the same structure.

Example:

```
{
  "albert":{ 
       "age": 35
  }, 
  "sarah":{ 
       "age": 33
  },
  "otto":{
        "age":27
  }
}
```

with jq the output should  be an array and look like this:

```
[
  {"name":"albert","age":35},
  {"name":"sarah"","age":32},
  {"name":"otto","age":27},
]
```

Can somebody help me?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

```
to_entries
| map( {name: .key, age: .value.age} )
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.